# After searching once not able to search again

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

File Structure:

[image]

I have a input textbox , there i type something and pass that value to a function named `onRecievingResults()` and pass that value to another component using params and make `http` request and i get the results if i search again i am not able to get the results.

**faq.component.ts**

```
onRecievingResults() {
    this.router.navigate(['results', this.inputValue], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

**search-results.component.ts**

```
export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnInit {
data: any[];
item: any[];

inputValue;
constructor(private faqService: FaqService,private route: ActivatedRoute,) {
}
ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(
(params : Params) => {
 this.inputValue = params["inputValue"];
    }
);
  this.faqService.getServers(this.inputValue)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.item = data.items;
        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }  
}
```

**faq.service.ts**

```
getServers(inputValue) {
    return this.http.get(Staticdata.apiBaseUrl + "/2.2/search/advanced?key="+ Staticdata.key +"&access_token="+ Staticdata.access_token +"&/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&closed=True&title=" + inputValue + Staticdata.redirectUrl + "&filter="+ Staticdata.filters)
        .map(
        (response: Response) => {
            const items = response.json();
            return items;
        },
    )
    .catch(
        (error: Response) => {
            return Observable.throw(error);
        }
  );
}
```

Comment: A component will initialize only once.

Comment: bind `valueChanges` on your formcontrol

Comment: how do reintialize it again and again so that i can search for diffrent values? @Hoyen

Comment: example plz @BhavikPatel

Comment: you initialize it once and whenever the value is changed it will tirgger it. Its like binding an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appcomponent.html

```
<app-child [items]="items"></app-child>
<form [formGroup]="searchForm"><input formControlName="search"></form>
```

appcomponent.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
 searchForm: FormGroup;
 search= new FormControl();
 searchField: FormControl;
items;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private service: AppService){}

     ngOnInit(){
        this.searchField = new FormControl();
        this.searchForm = this.fb.group({search: this.searchField})

               this.searchField.valueChanges
               .debounceTime(400)
               .switchMap(res =>  this.service.search(res))
              .subscribe(res => {this.items = res});}
```

app-child.component.html

```
<h3>child component Search bar values of parent component</h3>
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{item}}
    </div>
```

app-child.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    templateUrl: './appchild.component.html'
})
export class appChildComponent {
@Input()
    items;
}
```

As you requested this all about search bar about service reference check this [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/SIltBL/)

Comment: How can i do this if i have inputbox in parent component which is **faq.component.html** and the results page in the child component **search-results.component.html**

Comment: could you please do it for the above code that i posted @k11k2

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the changes in the input:

```
@Output() searchEvent: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

this.searchBox
  .valueChanges
  .debounceTime(200)
  .subscribe((event) => this.searchEvent.emit(event));
```

Comment: in which component should i add this

Comment: `@output` is used to send data from child to parent component and it should be used in child component.

Comment: i just want to search again and again @k11k2

Comment: Add it to your SearchResultsComponent.

Comment: what is this.searchBox ? @SonuKapoor