# how to create search bar dropdown in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have created below search bar component which interacts with API every time a key is pressed.

```
<div class="fill-remaining-space">
  <md-input-container class="example-full-width" color="accent">
    <md-icon mdPrefix>search</md-icon>
    <input type="text" mdInput #input (keyup)="search(input)">
    <md-icon mdSuffix *ngIf="input.value.length > 0" (click)="input.value=''">clear</md-icon>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Now I am getting results array in my component.ts file. I want to show a dropdown below this search bar when results are fetched from db.
I tried doing multiple things like applying *ngIf on list. but all in vain.

Is there any simple solution which can allow me to show a dropdown list after I start typings characters in search box input?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-typeahead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486330/after-searching-once-not-able-to-search-again/45487366#45487366 may help you